# Monkeyrunner script doesn't run, but commands work

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

If I run Monkeyrunner manually and execute the following 3 commands:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

device.press('KEYCODE_HOME', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

Everything works, I see that the home key is pressed. However, if I save those 3 commands into a .py file, and then try to run the file, I get the following:

```
....\MonkeyRunner Scripts>monkeyrunner BasicTest.py
Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO,
WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

I decided to try the -v switch to see what it say's, and I got the following:

```
....\MonkeyRunner Scripts>monkeyrunner -v BasicTest.
py
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad level "BasicT
est.py"
        at java.util.logging.Level.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions.processOptions(MonkeyRun
nerOptions.java:130)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter
.java:179)
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Try using script's absolute path

Comment: I tried that, still see the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: I got it to work right on a different machine. I'll have to play around with the machine I"m having trouble on and report back.

Comment: If the other machine was Linux, then the problem is with Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but the only way I can get the scripts to work is run monkeyrunner from it's directory, rather than placing the path to monkeyrunner in my PATH. Also, the script itself also has to be in the same directly as the monkeyrunner.exe.

Does this make any sense to anyone out there?

Comment: Google being Google at documentation

Comment: This does not make any sense...2021 it still needs this workaround

Answer (score 0):

it works on any folder sending the content of the file as input

monkeyrunner < ./my_script.py